# Gradual filling of NA values depending on the auxiliary rule table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to iterate through a big data frame with millions or rows to fill the missing data. And it takes me ages to iterate through. Thinking to update my code by converting data frame to multi-dimensional array or to a dictionary.

Now the question is which one is faster to iterate through.

My code is as below:

```
# Loop through the inventory and production dataframes to fill the missing values in the inventory dataframe
for index, prod_row in summ_prod.iterrows():
    for i in range(0,prod_row[2]):
        for inv_index in inv_df1.index:
            if  ((inv_df1.iloc[inv_index, 3] == prod_row[1]) and (pd.isna(inv_df1.iloc[inv_index, 8])):
                inv_df1.iloc[inv_index, 6] = prod_row[4] #Sales Order
                inv_df1.iloc[inv_index, 8] = prod_row[5] #Customer
                inv_df1.iloc[inv_index, 9] = prod_row[6] #Market
                inv_df1.iloc[inv_index, 10] = prod_row[7] * float(inv_df1.iloc[inv_index,4]) #Total value
                inv_df1.iloc[inv_index, 11] = prod_row[7] #AUD/kg
                break
```

Sample dfs:
'inv'

```
    ,Lot No.,Slaughter Date,Item No.,Quantity,Status,Sales Order,Sales Invoice,Customer,Market,Total Value,$/kg 
0,20230630-003001,30/06/2023,4161,10.2,SOH,,,,,,
1,20230630-003002,30/06/2023,4161,11.15,SOH,,,,,,
2,20230630-003003,30/06/2023,4161,11.95,SOH,,,,,,
3,20230630-003004,30/06/2023,4161,10.3,SOH,,,,,,
4,20230630-003005,30/06/2023,4161,10.85,SOH,,,,,,
5,20230630-003006,30/06/2023,4161,10.25,SOH,,,,,,
6,20230630-003007,30/06/2023,4161,11.2,SOH,,,,,,
7,20230630-003010,30/06/2023,4161,11.05,SOH,,,,,,
8,20230630-003008,30/06/2023,4161,11.05,SOH,,,,,,
9,20230630-003009,30/06/2023,4161,10.85,SOH,,,,,,
10,20230630-003011,30/06/2023,4161,10.95,SOH,,,,,,
11,20230630-003012,30/06/2023,4161,9.8,SOH,,,,,,
12,20230703-001001,30/06/2023,14101,13.1,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,229.68 ,21.04 
13,20230703-001002,30/06/2023,14101,11.3,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,198.12 ,21.04 
14,20230703-001003,30/06/2023,14101,11.8,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,206.88 ,21.04 
15,20230703-001004,30/06/2023,14101,11.7,Sale,10004505,10006247,AWM,DOMESTIC,179.40 ,18.40 
16,20230703-003001,30/06/2023,14101,12.2,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,213.90 ,21.04 
17,20230703-001005,30/06/2023,14101,11.55,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,202.50 ,21.04 
18,20230703-001006,30/06/2023,14101,11.55,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,202.50 ,21.04 
19,20230703-001007,30/06/2023,14101,12,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,210.39 ,21.04 
20,20230703-007001,30/06/2023,14101,12.05,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,211.27 ,21.04 
21,20230703-007002,30/06/2023,14101,10,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,175.32 ,21.04 
22,20230703-007003,30/06/2023,14101,11.95,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,209.51 ,21.04 
23,20230703-003002,30/06/2023,14101,9.95,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,174.45 ,21.04 
24,20230703-001008,30/06/2023,14101,11.25,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,197.24 ,21.04 
25,20230703-003003,30/06/2023,14101,10.4,Sale,10004505,10006247,AWM,DOMESTIC,159.47 ,18.40 
26,20230703-001009,30/06/2023,14101,10.95,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,191.98 ,21.04 
27,20230703-007004,30/06/2023,14101,12.15,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,213.02 ,21.04 
28,20230703-007005,30/06/2023,14101,11.9,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,208.64 ,21.04 
29,20230703-007006,30/06/2023,14101,11.75,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,206.01 ,21.04 
30,20230703-007007,30/06/2023,14101,11.65,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,204.25 ,21.04 
31,20230703-007008,30/06/2023,14101,13.05,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,228.80 ,21.04 
32,20230703-007009,30/06/2023,14101,13.2,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,231.43 ,21.04 
33,20230703-007010,30/06/2023,14101,12.3,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,215.65 ,21.04 
34,20230703-007011,30/06/2023,14101,12.1,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,212.14 ,21.04 
35,20230703-001010,30/06/2023,14101,8.55,Sale,10004505,10006247,TCI,USA,149.90 ,21.04 
36,20230710-001032,7/07/2023,4141,12.2,Sale,10004505,10006247,PPT,DOMESTIC,44.73 ,4.40 
37,20230710-007012,7/07/2023,4141,11.45,Sale,10004505,10006247,PPT,DOMESTIC,41.98 ,4.40 
38,20230710-001033,7/07/2023,4141,12.6,Sale,10004505,10006247,PPT,DOMESTIC,46.20 ,4.40 
39,20230710-003006,7/07/2023,4141,11.75,Sale,10004505,10006247,PPT,DOMESTIC,43.08 ,4.40 
40,20230710-001010,7/07/2023,4143,13.55,Sale,10004505,10006247,PPT,DOMESTIC,71.14 ,6.30 
41,20230710-001011,7/07/2023,4143,15.4,Sale,10004505,10006247,PPT,DOMESTIC,80.85 ,6.30 
42,20230710-001012,7/07/2023,4143,15.75,Sale,10004505,10006247,PPT,DOMESTIC,82.69 ,6.30 
43,20230710-001001,7/07/2023,14100,10.7,SOH,,,,,,
44,20230710-001002,7/07/2023,14100,11.4,SOH,,,,,,
45,20230710-001003,7/07/2023,14100,10.45,SOH,,,,,,
46,20230710-001004,7/07/2023,14100,10.1,SOH,,,,,,
47,20230710-003001,7/07/2023,14100,10.95,SOH,,,,,,
48,20230710-001005,7/07/2023,14100,11.05,SOH,,,,,,
49,20230710-007001,7/07/2023,14100,10.3,SOH,,,,,,
50,20230710-001006,7/07/2023,14100,9.35,SOH,,,,,,
51,20230710-001007,7/07/2023,14100,11.7,SOH,,,,,,
52,20230710-001008,7/07/2023,14100,10.55,SOH,,,,,,
53,20230710-001009,7/07/2023,14100,10.2,Sale,10004505,10006247,AWM,DOMESTIC,113.12 ,13.31 
54,20230710-007002,7/07/2023,14100,11.6,Sale,10004505,10006247,AWM,DOMESTIC,128.64 ,13.31 
55,20230710-007003,7/07/2023,14100,11.15,Sale,10004505,10006247,AWM,DOMESTIC,123.65 ,13.31 
56,20230710-007004,7/07/2023,14100,10.2,Sale,10004505,10006247,AWM,DOMESTIC,113.12 ,13.31 
57,20230710-001010,7/07/2023,14100,9.7,Sale,10004505,10006247,AWM,DOMESTIC,107.57 ,13.31 
58,20230710-003002,7/07/2023,14100,10.6,Sale,10004505,10006247,AWM,DOMESTIC,117.55 ,13.31 
59,20230710-001011,7/07/2023,14100,10.6,Sale,10004549,10006263,AWM,DOMESTIC,117.55 ,13.31 
60,20230710-001012,7/07/2023,14100,9.65,Sale,10004549,10006263,AWM,DOMESTIC,107.02 ,13.31 
61,20230710-001001,7/07/2023,14101,12.4,SOH,,,,,,
62,20230710-001002,7/07/2023,14101,11.75,SOH,,,,,,
63,20230710-001003,7/07/2023,14101,11.15,SOH,,,,,,
64,20230710-001004,7/07/2023,14101,12.15,SOH,,,,,,
65,20230710-001005,7/07/2023,14101,12.8,SOH,,,,,,
66,20230710-001006,7/07/2023,14101,12.35,SOH,,,,,,
67,20230710-001007,7/07/2023,14101,12.5,SOH,,,,,,
68,20230710-001008,7/07/2023,14101,10.9,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,189.25 ,20.83 
69,20230710-001009,7/07/2023,14101,11.9,SOH,,,,,,
70,20230710-001010,7/07/2023,14101,11.6,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,201.40 ,20.83 
71,20230710-001011,7/07/2023,14101,12.95,SOH,,,,,224.42 ,20.80 
72,20230710-001012,7/07/2023,14101,11.25,SOH,,,,,,
73,20230710-001014,7/07/2023,14101,12.65,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,219.63 ,20.83 
74,20230710-001015,7/07/2023,14101,11.95,SOH,,,,,,
75,20230710-001013,7/07/2023,14101,13.3,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,230.92 ,20.83 
76,20230710-001016,7/07/2023,14101,11.2,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,194.46 ,20.83 
77,20230710-001017,7/07/2023,14101,12.8,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,222.24 ,20.83 
78,20230710-001018,7/07/2023,14101,11.2,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,194.46 ,20.83 
79,20230710-001019,7/07/2023,14101,11.05,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,191.85 ,20.83 
80,20230710-003001,7/07/2023,14101,11.75,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,204.00 ,20.83 
81,20230710-001020,7/07/2023,14101,12.6,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,218.76 ,20.83 
82,20230710-001021,7/07/2023,14101,11.6,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,201.40 ,20.83 
83,20230710-001022,7/07/2023,14101,13.55,SOH,,,,,,
84,20230710-001023,7/07/2023,14101,11.65,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,202.27 ,20.83 
85,20230710-001024,7/07/2023,14101,12.75,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,221.37 ,20.83 
86,20230710-007001,7/07/2023,14101,12,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,208.35 ,20.83 
87,20230710-003002,7/07/2023,14101,12.05,SOH,,,,,,
88,20230710-007002,7/07/2023,14101,11.85,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,205.74 ,20.83 
89,20230710-007003,7/07/2023,14101,12.75,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,221.37 ,20.83 
90,20230710-003003,7/07/2023,14101,12.7,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,220.50 ,20.83 
91,20230710-001025,7/07/2023,14101,11.35,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,197.06 ,20.83 
92,20230710-001026,7/07/2023,14101,10.75,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,186.64 ,20.83 
93,20230710-001027,7/07/2023,14101,12.95,SOH,,,,,,
94,20230710-001028,7/07/2023,14101,10.5,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,182.30 ,20.83 
95,20230710-007004,7/07/2023,14101,11.45,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,198.80 ,20.83 
96,20230710-007005,7/07/2023,14101,12.2,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,211.82 ,20.83 
97,20230710-001029,7/07/2023,14101,11.9,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,206.61 ,20.83 
98,20230710-001030,7/07/2023,14101,11.85,SOH,,,,,,
99,20230710-001031,7/07/2023,14101,12.65,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,219.63 ,20.83 
100,20230710-001032,7/07/2023,14101,13.6,Sale,10004549,10006263,TCI,USA,236.12 ,20.83 
101,20230710-001001,7/07/2023,14104,14.4,SOH,,,,,,
102,20230710-001002,7/07/2023,14104,17,SOH,,,,,,
103,20230710-001003,7/07/2023,14104,15.5,SOH,,,,,,
104,20230710-001004,7/07/2023,14104,14.2,SOH,,,,,,
105,20230710-001005,7/07/2023,14104,16.3,SOH,,,,,,
106,20230710-001006,7/07/2023,14104,17.75,SOH,,,,,,
107,20230710-001007,7/07/2023,14104,15.75,SOH,,,,,,
108,20230710-001008,7/07/2023,14104,15.8,SOH,,,,,,
109,20230710-001009,7/07/2023,14104,16.7,SOH,,,,,,
110,20230710-001010,7/07/2023,14104,15.65,SOH,,,,,,
111,20230710-001011,7/07/2023,14104,16.75,SOH,,,,,,
112,20230710-001012,7/07/2023,14104,15.7,SOH,,,,,,
113,20230710-001013,7/07/2023,14104,15.6,SOH,,,,,,
114,20230710-001014,7/07/2023,14104,16.05,SOH,,,,,,
115,20230710-001015,7/07/2023,14104,18.1,SOH,,,,,,
116,20230710-001016,7/07/2023,14104,15.85,SOH,,,,,,
117,20230710-001017,7/07/2023,14104,18.7,SOH,,,,,,
118,20230710-001018,7/07/2023,14104,18.85,SOH,,,,,,
119,20230710-001019,7/07/2023,14104,16.7,SOH,,,,,,
120,20230710-001020,7/07/2023,14104,16.05,SOH,,,,,,
121,20230710-001021,7/07/2023,14104,16.85,SOH,,,,,,
122,20230710-001022,7/07/2023,14104,17.3,SOH,,,,,,
123,20230710-001023,7/07/2023,14104,17.35,SOH,,,,,,
124,20230710-001024,7/07/2023,14104,16.2,SOH,,,,,,
125,20230710-001025,7/07/2023,14104,16.9,SOH,,,,,,
126,20230710-001026,7/07/2023,14104,16.45,SOH,,,,,,
127,20230710-001027,7/07/2023,14104,13.9,SOH,,,,,,
128,20230710-001028,7/07/2023,14104,16.4,SOH,,,,,,
129,20230710-001029,7/07/2023,14104,20.05,SOH,,,,,,
130,20230710-007001,7/07/2023,14104,17.6,SOH,,,,,,
131,20230710-001030,7/07/2023,14104,13.4,SOH,,,,,,
132,20230710-001031,7/07/2023,14104,17.9,SOH,,,,,,
133,20230710-001032,7/07/2023,14104,16.75,SOH,,,,,,
134,20230710-001033,7/07/2023,14104,15.5,SOH,,,,,,
135,20230710-001034,7/07/2023,14104,14.85,SOH,,,,,,
136,20230710-001035,7/07/2023,14104,19.5,SOH,,,,,,
137,20230710-001036,7/07/2023,14104,17.6,SOH,,,,,,
138,20230710-001037,7/07/2023,14104,16.2,SOH,,,,,,
139,20230710-001038,7/07/2023,14104,16.45,SOH,,,,,,
140,20230710-001039,7/07/2023,14104,16.35,SOH,,,,,,
141,20230710-001040,7/07/2023,14104,15.95,SOH,,,,,,
142,20230710-001041,7/07/2023,14104,15.45,SOH,,,,,,
143,20230710-001042,7/07/2023,14104,16.4,Sale,10004549,10006263,AWM,DOMESTIC,278.80 ,20.40 
144,20230710-007002,7/07/2023,14104,17.55,Sale,10004549,10006263,AWM,DOMESTIC,298.35 ,20.40 
145,20230710-007003,7/07/2023,14104,15.8,Sale,10004549,10006263,AWM,DOMESTIC,268.60 ,20.40 
146,20230710-001043,7/07/2023,14104,17.45,Sale,10004549,10006263,AWM,DOMESTIC,296.65 ,20.40 
147,20230710-001044,7/07/2023,14104,16.8,Sale,10004549,10006263,AWM,DOMESTIC,285.60 ,20.40 
148,20230710-001045,7/07/2023,14104,16.4,Sale,10004549,10006263,AWM,DOMESTIC,278.80 ,20.40 
149,20230710-001046,7/07/2023,14104,17.15,Sale,10004549,10006263,AWM,DOMESTIC,291.55 ,20.40 
150,20230710-007004,7/07/2023,14104,17.4,SOH,,,,,,
151,20230710-003001,7/07/2023,14104,5.5,SOH,,,,,,
152,20230717-001001,14/07/2023,4141,11.9,SOH,,,,,,
153,20230717-001002,14/07/2023,4141,11.9,SOH,,,,,,
154,20230717-001003,14/07/2023,4141,11.75,SOH,,,,,,
155,20230717-001004,14/07/2023,4141,12.55,SOH,,,,,,
156,20230717-001005,14/07/2023,4141,12.55,SOH,,,,,,
157,20230717-007001,14/07/2023,4141,12.1,SOH,,,,,,
158,20230717-001006,14/07/2023,4141,12.05,SOH,,,,,,
159,20230717-001007,14/07/2023,4141,10.45,SOH,,,,,,
160,20230717-001008,14/07/2023,4141,11.05,SOH,,,,,,
161,20230717-001009,14/07/2023,4141,10.5,SOH,,,,,,
162,20230717-001010,14/07/2023,4141,10.35,SOH,,,,,,
163,20230717-001011,14/07/2023,4141,11.45,SOH,,,,,,
164,20230717-001012,14/07/2023,4141,11.1,SOH,,,,,,
165,20230717-003001,14/07/2023,4141,9.55,SOH,,,,,,
166,20230717-003002,14/07/2023,4141,11.05,SOH,,,,,,
167,20230717-001013,14/07/2023,4141,8.9,SOH,,,,,,
168,20230717-001014,14/07/2023,4141,10.9,SOH,,,,,,
169,20230717-003003,14/07/2023,4141,10.9,SOH,,,,,,
170,20230717-001015,14/07/2023,4141,9.5,SOH,,,,,,
171,20230717-007002,14/07/2023,4141,10.5,SOH,,,,,,
172,20230717-001016,14/07/2023,4141,12.75,SOH,,,,,,
173,20230717-003004,14/07/2023,4141,10.5,SOH,,,,,,
174,20230717-001017,14/07/2023,4141,12.05,SOH,,,,,,
175,20230717-001018,14/07/2023,4141,9.95,SOH,,,,,,
176,20230717-001019,14/07/2023,4141,11.6,SOH,,,,,,
177,20230717-003005,14/07/2023,4141,9.45,SOH,,,,,,
178,20230717-001020,14/07/2023,4141,12.35,SOH,,,,,,
179,20230717-003006,14/07/2023,4141,10.9,SOH,,,,,,
180,20230717-001021,14/07/2023,4141,7.25,SOH,,,,,,
181,20230717-001022,14/07/2023,4141,9.85,SOH,,,,,,
182,20230717-003007,14/07/2023,4141,10.45,SOH,,,,,,
183,20230717-001023,14/07/2023,4141,9.75,SOH,,,,,,
184,20230717-001024,14/07/2023,4141,11.2,SOH,,,,,,
185,20230717-001025,14/07/2023,4141,8.25,SOH,,,,,,
186,20230717-003008,14/07/2023,4141,11.4,SOH,,,,,,
187,20230717-001026,14/07/2023,4141,9.7,SOH,,,,,,
188,20230717-001027,14/07/2023,4141,10.35,SOH,,,,,,
189,20230717-001028,14/07/2023,4141,10.2,SOH,,,,,,
190,20230717-001029,14/07/2023,4141,11.7,SOH,,,,,,
191,20230717-001030,14/07/2023,4141,11.85,SOH,,,,,,
192,20230717-001031,14/07/2023,4141,10.9,SOH,,,,,,
193,20230717-001032,14/07/2023,4141,11.55,SOH,,,,,,
194,20230717-001033,14/07/2023,4141,11.05,SOH,,,,,,
195,20230717-001034,14/07/2023,4141,12.9,SOH,,,,,,
196,20230717-001035,14/07/2023,4141,12.85,SOH,,,,,,
197,20230717-001036,14/07/2023,4141,13.1,SOH,,,,,,
198,20230717-001037,14/07/2023,4141,10.7,SOH,,,,,,
199,20230717-001038,14/07/2023,4141,11.4,SOH,,,,,,
200,20230717-001039,14/07/2023,4141,9.8,SOH,,,,,,
201,20230717-001001,14/07/2023,4143,13.75,SOH,,,,,,
202,20230717-001002,14/07/2023,4143,13.6,SOH,,,,,,
203,20230717-001003,14/07/2023,4143,13.3,SOH,,,,,,
```

'prod'

```
,Item No.,Cartons,KG,SO No.,Customer,Market,AUD/kg
0,4141,27,328.05,SO-4529,PPT,DOMESTIC,5.50
1,4141,22,274.9,SO-4529,UMC,DOMESTIC,5.50
2,4143,12,164.85,SO-4529,PPT,DOMESTIC,7.82
3,4161,12,61.54761904761905,AWMS-1707,AWS,DOMESTIC,12.4
4,14101,16,196.95238095238096,SO-4548,AWS,DOMESTIC,12.4
5,14101,55,97.9453125,SO-4548,AWS,DOMESTIC,23.2
6,14101,18,65.296875,SO-4522,FSP,SINGAPORE,23.2
7,14104,72,119.7109375,SO-4547,GP,TAIWAN,25.7
8,14104,2,65.296875,SO-4552,UMC,DOMESTIC,23.4
```

Comment: btw what is `summ_prod` and why do you need a middle loop?

Comment: Summ_prod and prod are same. Df summ_prod's each row's data will fill df inv's missing data summ_prod['Cartons] number of time. @Vitalizzare

Comment: You are right. It should be row[2]. @Vitalizzare

Comment: My apology. It was a condition that I add later. Ignore that condition please. @Vitalizzare

Comment: Both data sets are in csv format. You can copy them in a empty csv file and upload them in python. @Vitalizzare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna assume that you're working with Pandas or a similar tool.

So here's the main problem which I can see in your code: you're not using labels and as a result you get easily confused about column indexes. I'd say, there's even more serious problem which can blow in your face in some future: you're mixing hard indexing and labels, as in this part:

```
for inv_index in inv_df1.index:
    if ((inv_df1.iloc[inv_index, 3] ...
```

As far as you're iterating over indexes, it's dangerous to use them in `.iloc` because your actual index may be different from the row's positional number. IMO in the above excerption, it would be safer to use something like `for inv_index in range(len(inv_df1)): ...`.

Next problem, you are only using Pandas as a data container. Let's see if we can improve the code using DataFrame's features:

```
inv = pd.read_csv(inv_csv_file, index_col=0)
prod = pd.read_csv(prod_csv_file, index_col=0)

for i in prod.index:
    eq_Item_No = inv['Item No.'] == prod.at[i, 'Item No.']      # mark required "Item No."
    has_NA_Customer = inv['Customer'].isna()                    # mark void Customers
    selected = eq_Item_No & has_NA_Customer                     # select required "Item No" with empty Customer
    selected &= selected.cumsum() <= prod.at[i, 'Cartons']      # restrict selection to the first prod[Cartons] number of selected rows
    
    inv.loc[selected, 'Sales Order'] = prod.at[i, 'SO No.']     
    inv.loc[selected, 'Customer'] = prod.at[i, 'Customer']
    inv.loc[selected, 'Market'] = prod.at[i, 'Market']
    inv.loc[selected, '$/kg'] = prod.at[i, 'AUD/kg'] 
    inv.loc[selected, 'Total Value'] = \
        prod.at[i, 'AUD/kg'] * inv.loc[selected, 'Quantity']    # broadcast multiplication
```

On my hardware, the execution of this code will take about 18 ms, while the original code on the proposed data will take 3.25 s. I believe this result can be improved by eliminating the handling of the "Cartons" column, which resembles intermediate calculations, probably related to the "Slaughter Date" values previously featured in the source code.

---

#### P.S.

Let's see how the following line works:

```
selected &= selected.cumsum() <= prod.at[i, 'Cartons']
```

First, I'd like to rewrite it like this:

```
series &= series.cumsum() <= limit
```

where `series` is `pandas.Series` of boolean type, and `limit` is some number (to make sense, some non-negative integer, but not necessarily).

- `series &= something` is [augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) meaning `series = series & something`
- `series.cumsum()` is a [cumulative sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), which in case of boolean values increments with each `True` value
- `series & (series.cumsum() <= limit)` returns all the values of `series` with only first `limit` number of `True`

For example, let's say `limit = 4; series = pd.Series([0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1], dtype=bool)`:

| series | cumsum | cumsum <= 4 | series & (cumsum <= 4) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | 0 | True | False |
| True | 1 | True | True |
| True | 2 | True | True |
| False | 2 | True | False |
| True | 3 | True | True |
| False | 3 | True | False |
| True | 4 | True | True |
| True | 5 | False | False |
| True | 6 | False | False |

When we use transformed `series` in the above example as [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), we only get records placed where the first 4 `True` values of the original `series` occur.

Comment: Congratulation. It's really faster. Can you please explain a bit on `selected &= selected.cumsum() <= prod.at[i, 'Cartons']` . If possible any reference that explain. @Vitalizzare